# Как получить ответ json от apivk, распарсить его и передать в метод

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, cors, jsonp

Здравствуйте! помогите пожалуйста с запросом, второй день сижу курю но безрезультатно (( В общем ...

есть url `https://pu.vk.com/cхххххх/upload.php?act=do_add&mid...`
Нужно загрузить картинки jpg мультиаплоадом через форму с моего сайта в альбом вк,
как многим известно загрузка проходит в 3 этапа..

1. получение ссылки - photos.getUploadServer (готово)
2. получение ответа json через ссылку от vk
3. сохранение - photos.save

если я самым простым способом получаю json просто написав action="url"

то он тупо перенаправляет на этот файл и показывает ответ json, проблема в том что мне надо брать инфу из этого ответа и я не могу этим ответом управлять

получается надо что то на js-ajax или curl.. чтобы из json строки мне значения занести в переменные и дальше указать в методе photos.save
так вот..
форма..

```
<form id="imageform" method="POST" name="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="clear:both" action="https://pu.vk.com/cхххххх/upload.php?act=do_add&mid..." >
   <input type='file' name='file1' id='photoimg' multiple='true' accept='image' onchange='getName();'/>
   <button type='submit' name='go-files' id='go-files'></button>
</form>
```

js-ajax-jsonp не использовал т.к. походу там файлы нельзя передавать

curl

```
$img_src = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];
$data = array('file1'=>'@'.$img_src);
$url = 'https://pu.vk.com/cхххххх/upload.php?act=do_add&mid...';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: multipart/form-data"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($response);
```

curl ответ дает но выводит $response photos_list - пустой (

```
{"server":630719,"photos_list":"[]","aid":ххххххххх,"hash":"c4b106220a25ebb7a84b774efc1c7f97","gid":хххххххх}
```

XMLHttpRequest

```
$('#go-files').click(function(){
   var form = $('#imageform');
   var formData = new FormData(form);
   var XHR = ("onload" in new XMLHttpRequest()) ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest;
   var xhr = new XHR();
   //var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open("POST", "https://pu.vk.com/c630719/upload.php?act=do_add...", true);
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
         if(xhr.status == 200) {
            var data = xhr.responseXML;
            console.log(data);
            //if(data == "true") {
            //   $("#header2").replaceWith("<p>Принято!<p>");
            //} else {
            //    $("#header2").replaceWith("<p >Ошибка! Обновите страницу...<p>");
            //}
         }
      }
   };
   //xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
   var data = xhr.responseXML;
   console.log(data);
   xhr.send(formData);
});
```

XMLHttpRequest не вдоль не поперек не дает ответ и присылает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

js-ajax-cors тоже не помог, потому что консоль говорит нельзя отправить ), подключаю его делая require_once в файле где располагается форма, при его наличии и без в консоли ошибка

```
<?php
function enableCORS() {
    // Allow from any origin
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
    }
    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:     {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
        exit(0);
    }
    return true;
}
?>
```

проще говоря нужно получить ответ json
его части занести в переменные и передать в php метод photos.save

Comment: Попробуйте для начала поменять браузер, например отправить запрос из I.E., вместо Chrome, я сначала нашёл рабочий вариант кода, а потом настраивал заголовки под браузеры